# Whats wrong with this SQL clause?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update the column amount if the buyid (primary key) is a specific value.

```
UPDATE portfolio set amount=40 WHERE buyid=3
```

I work with JDBC and MySql, everytime I try to execute the statement i get the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'buyid=3' at
>   line 1

table structure of portfolio:

```
buyid int
username varchar
stockname varchar
priceperstock float
amount int
```

Javasourcecode:

```
public void sellStock(int buyid, int amount, float currentprice, String user) {

...

    try {
        stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(fetchedamount);
        System.out.println("UPDATE portfolio
                            SET amount=" + fetchedamount
                        + " WHERE buyid=" + buyid);

        stmt.execute("UPDATE stockman.portfolio
                      SET amount=" + fetchedamount
                   + "WHERE buyid=" + buyid+"");
        // update capital
        newmoney = amount * currentprice + oldmoney;

    } catch (SQLException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how about datatype of `buyid`, also if you can share table structure

Comment: Are you able to run this query directly in mysql client? Is the data type of buyid numberic?

Comment: You might want to check the statement for hidden characters . . . spaces that are not really spaces, for instance (sometimes just re-typing the expression can fix some problems).

Comment: The query looks OK. It seems the `buyid` is not a number.

Comment: if i run it from myphpadmin it works.

Comment: Can you add the Java code which is giving the error?

Comment: Since it runs at myphppadmin, there is some wrong with your java code. It seems some extra character may added to you query while using it at java.

Comment: can you share your table Structure.

Comment: stockman is DB name?

Comment: try to replace WHERE clause to `WHERE stockman.buyid=" + buyid`

Answer (score 7):

At `stmt.execute()` Your generated query is like
`"UPDATE stockman.portfolio set amount=23WHERE buyid=54 "`

Here `23Where` is one whole string so you have to give space between these two.

Give space between *"* and *Where*  like the following:

```
" WHERE buyid="
```

And remove the last `+""`

Answer (score 0):

Just add space before Where it will solve the problem.

```
 stmt.execute("UPDATE stockman.portfolio
                  SET amount=" + fetchedamount
               + " WHERE buyid=" + buyid+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Repleace the `stm.execute` line with:
`stmt.execute("UPDATE stockman.portfolio SET amount=" + fetchedamount + " WHERE buyid=" + buyid+" ");`

Or:
`stmt.execute("UPDATE stockman.portfolio SET amount='" + fetchedamount + "' WHERE buyid='" + buyid+"' ");`